# "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." while update via Azure Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to update the useraccount property AccountEnabled but For some User account its throwing an Error.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make the app Company Admin. There are some discussions on the GitHub, see if the proposed Powershell workaround will work for you. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

I cant see more codes, so guess some reasons. You need AD authentication. Did you use Accesstoken and credential? Pls refer to [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/) to get more information.

*Keep contact if you have any questions.*